# Benchmarking matrices functions and calculations in R

Tags: r, benchmarking

I have managed to program several functions to perform matrices calculations in R such as:

**Determinants Calculation:**

```
Det_fn <- function(x){
if(nrow(x)!=ncol(x)) {
  print("Undefined")
} else
  if(nrow(x)==1 && ncol(x)==1) {
    DET <- x[1,1]; DET
  } else
    if(nrow(x)==2 && ncol(x)==2) {
      DET <- x[1,1]*x[2,2]-x[1,2]*x[2,1]; DET
    } else
      for(j in 1:ncol(x)){
        DET[j] <- (((-1)^(1+j))*x[1,j]*Det_fn(x[-1,-j]))
      }
  DET
  sum(DET)
}
```

**Cofactor signs matrix:**

```
Cof_fn <- function(x){
COF <- matrix(rep(0,ncol(x)), nrow(x), ncol(x)); COF
  for(i in 1:nrow(x)) {
    for(j in 1:ncol(x)) {
      COF[i,j] <- ((-1)^(i+j))
    }
  }
  COF
}
```

**Adjoint Matrix:**

```
Adj_fn <- function(x){
  ADJ <- matrix(rep(0,ncol(x)), nrow(x), ncol(x))
  for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
    for(j in 1:ncol(x)){
      ADJ[i,j] <- Det_fn(x[-j,-i])
    }
  }
  ADJ
}
```

**Inverse:**

```
Inv_fn <- function(x){
  ifelse(Det_fn(x)!=0, INV <- (((Adj_fn(x)/Det_fn(x))*Cof_fn(x))), print("Undefined, matrix is singular."))
  INV
}
```

I know that there are inbuilt functions in R to do this such as: `det()` and `solve()` but I just wanted to learn a little bit about matrices and some functions programming in R.  Now my question:

*How do I perform a benchmarking test on my functions and see how they perform compared to the inbuilt matrices functions in R?*

Comment: Have you tried using different benchmarking functions like `microbenchmark::microbenchmark` or `bench::mark` for this purpose ?

Comment: I have not @RonakShah.  I will look at those functions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Very pedestrian but it did the job as I expected... Using `Sys.time()`

```
# Benchmarking tests

V1 <- rnorm(100, mean=1.3, sd=0.6)
X <- matrix(V1, 10, 10)

Start1 <- Sys.time()

Det_fn(X)
Inv_fn(X)

End1 <- Sys.time()

End1-Start1

Start2 <- Sys.time()

det(X)
solve(X)

End2 <- Sys.time()

End2-Start2
abs(det(X)-Det_fn(X))

solve(X)-Inv_fn(X)
max(abs(solve(X)-Inv_fn(X)))
```

I just wanted to see how my functions `Det_fn()` and `Inv_fn()` compared to the inbuilt functions `det()` and `solve()` and the code I just posted did it for me.  The results are:

1. My `Det_fn()` and `Inv_fn()` took 2.536057 mins while `det()` and `solve()` took 0.003991842 secs.
2. The resulting determinants by using both methods are vistually the same with an error of 2.842171e-14.  The maximum absolute error in the inverse was  1.221245e-15

How can I optimize my determinant calculation? I must study that...